# Generate case range in bash

Tags: bash, switch-statement, range

I want to input two and three digit numbers into a function and output a case range, i.e., input `33` and `66` and output `3[3-9] | [4-5][0-9] | 6[0-6]` or input `33` and `666` and output `3[3-9] | [4-9][0-9] | [1-5][0-9][0-9] | 6[0-5][0-9] | 66[0-6]`

What are some ideas as to how? Thanks!

Comment: `if` statements are verbose, but in this case may be easier to get right, and may be more readable? Also, post text rather than images.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I replaced the image with readable code. I get that if statements are powerful enough to handle this, but I think using a function as the case range will be even more readable and concise.

Comment: What's `$a` in this code, and how does it relate to "a number" (first line of Q) and "two numbers" (second line of Q)?

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda,  `$a` is pseudocode for a positive integer.

Comment: I still don't understand.  You want to see if it falls within a certain range? And what do you mean by "delegate"?

Comment: Oh. I want to create a function that generates the range values, i.e., 33 and 66 from 50 (which I can do), and then (this is the point of the Q) to automate the case range i.e., `3[3-9] | [4-5][0-9] | 6[0-6]`

Comment: With delegate I just meant that I would replace the case range `[...] | [...]` with a function that uses $a as input and outputs two numbers and generates a case range as output. i.e., `generateCaseRange $a);;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115625/discussion-between-zaydek-and-kusalananda).

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jdamian, hi. I want to take two numbers and generate a case range, i.e., input `33` and `66` and output `3[3-9] | [4-5][0-9] | 6[0-6]`

Comment: @Jdamian I updated the question to represent the idea at its core.

Comment: there is no point in generating ranges if you do not plan to use ranges differently i.e are you planning to use different case bodies for different ranges (in your example .. 3 i guess?)

Comment: @ritesht93 Yes. The point is that the case ranges will change, and instead of hardcoding it, I want to generate it. I'm working on it now, just a bit difficult.

Comment: @zaydek Is it ok if there are multiple cases for `[4-5][0-9]` like this `4[0-9]` and `5[0-9]`?

Comment: @ritesht93 I prefer the least cases possible, i.e., `21` and `49` as `2[1-9] | [3-4][0-9]`

Comment: @zaydek but then it would be difficult to generate if there are multiple digits, are the number of digits fixed to 1 or 2, do you want it to handle 3 digits? what is the max number of digits it must be capable to handle?

Comment: @ritesht93 Great question! I'm just looking to work with single to triple digit numbers, i.e., `0-999`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115673/discussion-between-zaydek-and-ritesht93).

Comment: I think you want to generate a bash pattern matching a whole integer range.

Comment: You're right, @Jdamian. I got it working for all 2 by 2 digit numbers. Once I get it working for all 2 by 3 and 3 by 3 digit numbers, I will have solved it. I'll post the code when it's finished as a share.

Comment: @zaydek The recently update seems is inconsistent, such as ```33 and 666 and output 3[3-9] | [4-9][0-9]```. May be the best way is to re-thinking how to define the Range.

Comment: Just use two ranges one is begin and another is the end:
```
R     = begin [\| <end>]
begin = range
end   = range
range = [0-9]+
```
eg. ```33-666 -> 3[0-9] | [1-6][0-6][0-6]```

Comment: You would think that that works but it doesn't. `[1-6][0-6][0-6]` doesn't work because it doesn't consider `[7-9][7-9]` – it actually skips numbers like `177`, for example. bash is composing a literal range from the explicit sequence of integers given. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to share the final code: https://gist.github.com/zaydek/1627329f88c444f6d71d5cbc0cda616f :)

```
function enc {

    a=${1: -3:1}; b=${1: -2:1}; c=${1: -1}
    d=${2: -3:1}; e=${2: -2:1}; f=${2: -1}

    if   (( $[a] < $[d] )); then

        if   (( $b$c == 00 && $e$f == 99 )); then echo [$a-$d][0-9][0-9]
        elif (( $b$c == 00 )); then if (( $[a+1] < $d )); then echo [$a-$[d-1]][0-9][0-9] "|"; echo $(enc $[d]00 $d$e$f)
                                                          else echo $a[0-9][0-9] "|"; echo $(enc $[a+1]00 $d$e$f); fi

        else echo $(enc $a$b$c $[a]99) "|"; echo $(enc $[a+1]00 $d$e$f); fi

    elif (( $b < $e )); then

        if   (( $c == 0 && $f == 9 )); then echo $a[$b-$e][0-9]
        elif (( $c == 0 )); then if (( $[b+1] < $e )); then echo $a[$b-$[e-1]][0-9] "|"; echo $(enc $a$[e]0 $d$e$f)
                                                       else echo $a$b[0-9] "|"; echo $(enc $a$[e]0 $d$e$f); fi

        else echo $(enc $a$b$c $a$[b]9) "|"; echo $(enc $a$[b+1]0 $d$e$f); fi

    else

        if (( $c == $f )); then echo $a$b$c
        else echo $a$b[$c-$f]; fi; fi

}

function int {

    if [[ $1 = *.* ]]; then

        integer=${1%.*}
        decimal=${1#*.}

        if (( ${decimal:0:1} >= 5 )); then integer=$[integer+1]; fi

         echo $integer
    else echo $1; fi

}

function cse {

    minimum=$(int $(echo $1 $2 | awk '{ print ($1/$2)*( 90) }'))
    maximum=$(int $(echo $1 $2 | awk '{ print ($1/$2)*(110) }'))

    echo $(enc $minimum $maximum)

}

cse $1 $2
```

`cse` takes two inputs, converts them to decimals, and multiples each from a range, i.e., `90` and `110` for -10% and +10% error range, then passes off the `minimum` and `maximum` outputs as inputs to `enc` which is a recursive function that generates case range syntax (with syntax optimization).

Please note, bash does not appear to handle expressions for case ranges as expected or intended. Though, this code can be used to generate case ranges for all 2 to 3 digit numbers and then copied and pasted as inline code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the max 2 digits case for 0-99, I'd not used character's operations  indeed I'd tried math arithmetic.

The following are some output:

`./range.sh 1 39` -> `0[1-9] | [1-2][0-9] | 3[0-9]`

`./range.sh 21 49` -> `2[1-9] | [3-4][0-9]`

`./range.sh 33 66` -> `3[3-9] | [4-5][0-9] | 6[0-6]`

`./range.sh 33 99` -> `3[3-9] | [4-8][0-9] | 9[0-9]`

Here is my code: range.sh, hope it can provide some help for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

LHS=$1
RHS=$2
B2=10

D2=$(echo "($RHS-$LHS)/$B2" | bc)
if [[ ${D2} -gt 0 ]]; then
  S2=(`seq $(echo "$LHS/$B2" | bc) $(echo "$LHS/$B2+$D2" | bc)`)
  #echo ${S2[@]}
  C=${#S2[@]}
  #echo $C

  L1=$(echo "$LHS%$B2" | bc)
  if [[ ${L1} -lt 9 ]]; then 
    L1R="[${L1}-9]"
  else
    L1R="9"
  fi

  R1=$(echo "$RHS%$B2" | bc)
  if [[ ${R1} -gt 0 ]]; then
    R1R="[0-${R1}]"
  else
    R1R="[0-9]"
  fi

  if [[ ${C} -gt 3 ]]; then
    echo -n $(echo "$LHS/$B2" | bc)$L1R
    echo -n " | "[${S2[1]}-${S2[$C-2]}][0-9]
    echo -n " | "${S2[$C-1]}$R1R
  elif [[ ${C} -eq 3 ]]; then
    if [[ ${S2[0]} -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo -n 0$L1R
    else
      echo -n $(echo "$LHS/$B2" | bc)$L1R
    fi
    echo -n " | "[${S2[1]}-${S2[$C-1]}][0-9]
  fi

else
  echo [$LHS-$RHS]
fi

echo
```

Comment: Thanks @南山竹!! I just learned a new idea given your script.

I'm building a structure designed with embedded case statements instead of ifs and awk instead of bc for math. I'm also building shortcuts, so for example,

`30 99` outputs `[3-9][0-9]` instead of `3[0-9] | [4-8][0-9] | 9[0-9]`

Comment: I realized that processing 2 and 3 digit numbers is all I need to start, so I can skip single digit numbers.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect solving for two and three digit numbers.

Comment: Commented this above, wanted to share.

OK. I think what I can do is architect two functions. One that returns up to 6 outputs, so `12 943` is `12 19 99 899 939 943` and then a second function that looks at two inputs at a time and with `12 19` generates `1[2-9]`, next `19 99` generate `19 | [2-9][0-9]`, etc. using recursion until there's no more inputs. That should be far less code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic for 2 digit numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash
l=$1
h=$2

function get_nearest_upper_10th_mutlitple()
{
    v=$(($1+10))
    echo "${v%?}0"
}
function get_nearest_lower_10th_mutlitple()
{
    v=$1
    echo "${v%?}0"
}

temp="$(printf '%d' $l | wc -m)$(printf '%d' $h | wc -m)"
case $temp in
    11) echo "[$l-$h]"      ;;
    22|12)
        a=$([[ $(($l%10)) -eq 0 ]] && echo $l || echo $(($(get_nearest_upper_10th_mutlitple $l)-1)))
        if [[ $(printf '%d' $a | wc -m) -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo [$l-$a]
        else
            [[ $a -gt $l ]] && echo "${l%?}[${l#?}-${a#?}]" || echo $a
        fi

        b=$([[ $(($h%10)) -eq 0 ]] && echo $h || get_nearest_lower_10th_mutlitple $h)

        x=$((a+1))
        y=$((b-1))
        echo "[$(echo ${x%?}~${y%?} | sed 's/~/\n/g' | sort -n | uniq | paste -s -d '-')][${x#?}-${y#?}]"

        [[ $b -lt $h ]] && echo "${h%?}[${b#?}-${h#?}]" || echo $b
esac
```

Here are sample outputs:

```
$ ./script.bash 2 8
[2-8]
$ ./script.bash 2 6
[2-6]
$ ./script.bash 2 68
[2-9]
[1-5][0-9]
6[0-8]
$ ./script.bash 23 68
2[3-9]
[3-5][0-9]
6[0-8]
$ ./script.bash 23 99
2[3-9]
[3-8][0-9]
9[0-9]
$ ./script.bash 23 80
2[3-9]
[3-7][0-9]
80
$ ./script.bash 40 80
40
[4-7][1-9]
80
$ ./script.bash 40 80 | paste -s -d '|'
40|[4-7][1-9]|80
$ ./script.bash 35 55
3[5-9]
[4][0-9]
5[0-5]
```

You can use `paste -s -d '|'` to combine the individual ranges into a single ORed range.

You can use the existing functions which I've made to extend it for 3 digit numbers (I'll post the 3 digit version too after some time with different cases for `13` and `12`).

Comment: I really like this answer, for decomposing the first and last numbers, and using nearest numbers. Very clever from what I understand.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @ritesht93.

Comment: @zaydek welcome :).. Are you done with the logic build for 3 digits?

Comment: I finished a logic build for 2 digits with perfection, but it was too much code. I think I can radically simplify it with recursion, so I'm looking into it now.

Comment: I think it's gotta be possible with like 10-20 lines of code.

Comment: Why did `40 | [4-7][1-9] | 80` happen and not `4[0-9] | [5-7][0-9] | 80`, in your results?

Comment: OK. I think what I can do is architect two functions. One that returns up to 6 outputs, so `12 943` is `12 19 99 899 939 943` and then a second function that looks at two inputs at a time and with `12 19` generates `1[2-9]`, next `19 99` generate `19 | [2-9][0-9]`, etc. using recursion until there's no more inputs. That should be far less code.